# Does Germany's Union have a significant Eurosceptic faction?

Tags: european-union, germany, europe, christian-democrat

Do the CDU and CSU have a significant Eurosceptic faction (either hard or soft) which is represented at either grassroots or parliamentary level?  Or is support for the European project so deeply ingrained in the Christian Democratic DNA that they are uniformly supportive?  I associate the Union with people who (to me as a British Eurosceptic) seem like strong EU federalists, like Elmar Brock and Angela Merkel.

**EDIT - since people have asked for definitions, I define Euroscepticism as being significantly sceptical of, or hostile to, one, some or all of the following, in increasing degree to which these represent Euroscepticism:

Movement towards pan-European political institutions, in the form of a powerful presidency, common army or unified common fiscal policy

Closer fiscal and monetary integration

Existing fiscal and monetary integration and/or continued membership of the Euro

Continued membership of the European Union itself

In other words, a broad range of Eurosceptic beliefs that run across the spectrum covered by the ECR grouping and the ID grouping.

Comment: As a tangent, why does "Christian Democracy" not exist as a tag?

Comment: I'm not sure why there isn't a 'christian-democrat' tag or some such. I'd add one, but I don't know enough about it (in the US we don't have anything like a formal christian democracy movement). Let me search around the site a bit and see if such a tag is warranted.

Comment: There are 60 or 70 articles that mention 'Christian Democrat' or 'Christian democracy', and it is certainly a notable group, so I'll go ahead and add the tag for you.

Comment: There is no significant "Dexiteer" factions in the CDU/CSU. There are different views on the desirable level of integration, notably the question of common debt.

Comment: This seems to be in need of a more strict definition: skeptical of 'the Euro', the EU as it is, or *a* European integration in general?

Comment: Are you sure that's what the [ECR and ID are skeptical about](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50209/how-does-ecr-style-euroscepticism-differ-from-id-style-euroscepticism)? The ECR was mostly the UK Conservatives (which Brexit-ed) and the Polish PiS party, which is at odds with the EU on the "rule of law" etc. The ID (AfD, FN/RN) has even more extreme positions, I think.

Comment: @Fizz Well, the ideology of the ECR grouping has been quite flexible over the years.  But at the time of founding, it was a Cameronite soft-Eurosceptic group that genuinely took a third position between the EPP's federalism and hard-Euroscepticism

Answer (score 5):

With your definiton, yes, there are significant "Eurosceptic" factions in the CDU/CSU.

- They oppose a [common army](https://www.cducsu.de/sites/default/files/2018-11/Positionspapier%20Europa_2.pdf), preferring a cooperation of national armies instead.
- They are opposed to [Eurobonds](https://www.cducsu.eu/sites/www.cducsu.eu/files/downloads/positionspapiere/130130_grundsatzpapier_eurobonds.pdf), i.e. closer fiscal and monetary union.

Personally I do not consider it appropriate to characterize *these* positions as "Eurosceptic."